# Flutter SQL Switch does not reflect DB value on app restart

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am doing a simple boolean flag save example using Flutter SQFLite.

I have 2 switch flags:

1. Shows/Hides Input Field
2. Enables/Disables Input Field

SQFLite does not allow creating Boolean type table column.

Instead, developers can use int type to save Zero(false) or One(true).

In my example, the values are saved in the database.

When I change a flag selection from default value, then the db shows One otherwise the DB shows Zero.

Issue: SwitchFlag selections does not reflect saved DB value on app restart

Expected Behavior:
If a database value is zero, then the UI should show default.

If a database value is one, then the UI should show selected or non-default selection. This part is not working.

Could you please look at my code below and see how I could fix the issue. Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You

The example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class Flag1Fields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, myFlag];
  static final String id = '_id';
  static final String myFlag = 'Flag';
}

class myFlag1 {
  int? id;
  late int? isFlag = 0;
  myFlag1({required this.id, required this.isFlag});

  myFlag1 copy({int? id, int? isFlag, int? isVisFlag}) =>
      myFlag1(id: id ?? this.id, isFlag: isFlag ?? this.isFlag);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() =>
      {if (id != null) Flag1Fields.id: id, Flag1Fields.myFlag: isFlag};
  static myFlag1 fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => myFlag1(
      id: json[Flag1Fields.id] as int,
      isFlag: int.parse(json[Flag1Fields.myFlag].toString())
  );
}

class Flag2Fields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, myVisFlag];
  static final String id = '_id';
  static final String myVisFlag = 'VisFlag';
}

class myFlag2 {
  int? id;
  late int? isVisFlag = 0;
  myFlag2({required this.id,required this.isVisFlag});

  myFlag2 copy({int? id, int? isFlag, int? isVisFlag}) =>
      myFlag2(id: id ?? this.id, isVisFlag: isVisFlag ?? this.isVisFlag);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() =>
      {if (id != null) Flag2Fields.id: id, Flag2Fields.myVisFlag: isVisFlag};
  static myFlag2 fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => myFlag2(
      id: json[Flag2Fields.id] as int,
      isVisFlag: int.parse(json[Flag2Fields.myVisFlag].toString())
  );
}

class DBHelper {
  final String myFlag1Table = 'myFlag1Table';
  final String myFlag2Table = 'myFlag2Table';
  static const String myDatabase = 'myDB.db';

  DBHelper._init();
  static final DBHelper instance = DBHelper._init();
  static Database? db;

  Future<Database> get dataBase async {
    if (db != null) {
      return db!;
    } else {
      db = await initDB(myDatabase);
      return db!;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: createDB);
  }

  Future createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    var idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    var textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myFlag1Table (${Flag1Fields.id} $idType,${Flag1Fields.myFlag} $textType)''');
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myFlag2Table (${Flag2Fields.id} $idType,${Flag2Fields.myVisFlag} $textType)''');
  }

  Future<myFlag1> createFlag1(myFlag1 myflag1) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,myFlag1Table,myflag1.toJson());
    return myflag1.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future<myFlag2> createFlag2(myFlag2 myflag2) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,myFlag2Table,myflag2.toJson());
    return myflag2.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future<List<myFlag1>> readFlag1() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $myFlag1Table');
    final list = result.map((json) => myFlag1.fromJson(json)).toList();
    if (list.isNotEmpty)
      return list;
    else
      throw Exception('Empty List');
  }

  Future<List<myFlag2>> readFlag2() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $myFlag2Table');
    final list = result.map((json) => myFlag2.fromJson(json)).toList();
    if (list.isNotEmpty)
      return list;
    else
      throw Exception('Empty List');
  }

  Future<int> updateFlag1(myFlag1 myflag1) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return db.update(myFlag1Table, myflag1.toJson(), where: '${Flag1Fields.id} = ?', whereArgs: [myflag1.id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateFlag2(myFlag2 myflag2) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return db.update(myFlag2Table, myflag2.toJson(), where: '${Flag2Fields.id} = ?', whereArgs: [myflag2.id]);
  }

  Future<int> deleteFlag1(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return await db.delete(myFlag1Table, where: '${Flag1Fields.id} = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> deleteFlag2(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return await db.delete(myFlag2Table, where: '${Flag2Fields.id} = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    db.close();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();
  bool isInputVisible=false;
  bool isInputEnabled = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    createInputVisibleFlag1();
    createInputEnabledFlag2();
    readDBInputVisibleFlag1();
    readDBInputEnabledFlag2();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mc.dispose();
    DBHelper.instance.close();
    isLoading = false;
    isInputVisible = false;
    isInputEnabled = false;
    super.dispose();
  }

  createInputVisibleFlag1() async {
      setState(() {
        DBHelper.instance.createFlag1(myFlag1(id: 1, isFlag: 0));
      });
  }

  createInputEnabledFlag2() async {
      setState(() {
        DBHelper.instance.createFlag2(myFlag2(id: 1, isVisFlag: 0));
      });
  }

  readDBInputVisibleFlag1() async {
    final flags = await DBHelper.instance.readFlag1();
      flags.forEach((element) {
        if (element.isFlag == 0) {
          isInputVisible = false;
        }
        if (element.isFlag == 1){
          isInputVisible = true;
        }
      });
    return isInputVisible;
  }

  readDBInputEnabledFlag2() async {
    final flags = await DBHelper.instance.readFlag2();
      flags.forEach((element) {
        if (element.isVisFlag == 0) {
          isInputEnabled = false;
        }
        if (element.isVisFlag == 1){
          isInputEnabled = true;
        }
      });
    return isInputEnabled;
  }

  updateInputVisibleFlag1() async {
    if(isInputVisible==false){await DBHelper.instance.updateFlag1(myFlag1(id: 1, isFlag: 0));}
    if(isInputVisible==true){await DBHelper.instance.updateFlag1(myFlag1(id: 1, isFlag: 1));}
  }

  updateInputEnabledFlag2() async {
    if(isInputEnabled==false){await DBHelper.instance.updateFlag2(myFlag2(id: 1, isVisFlag: 0));}
    if(isInputEnabled==true){await DBHelper.instance.updateFlag2(myFlag2(id: 1, isVisFlag: 1));}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 20, child: Text(""));

    Widget mySwitch1 = SwitchListTile(title: Text("Visible Flag"),value: isInputVisible,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            isInputVisible = value;
            updateInputVisibleFlag1();
            readDBInputVisibleFlag1();
          });
        });

    Widget mySwitch2 = SwitchListTile(title: Text("Enabled Flag"),value: isInputEnabled,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            isInputEnabled = value;
            updateInputEnabledFlag2();
            readDBInputEnabledFlag2();
          });
        });

    Widget myinput = TextField(enabled: isInputEnabled,controller: mc,decoration:InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'));

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,body: SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,children: <Widget>[
                                space,space,mySwitch1,space,mySwitch2,space,Visibility(child:myinput,visible:isInputVisible),space])))]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> refreshFlag() async {
  setState(() => isLoading = true);
  final flags = await DBHelper.instance.readAllFlags();
  if (flags.isNotEmpty) {
    final flag = flags.first;
    setState(() {
      isInputVisible = flag.isVisFlag == 1;
      isInputEnabled = flag.isFlag == 1;
      isLoading = false;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      isInputVisible = false; 
      isInputEnabled = false; 
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! This fix is not working. Could you please help. Values in DB become zero after App restart. Thank You